# MySQL cli does not remember history of some commands

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I use linux OS with mysql database.

mysql CLI doesn't log some commands in `~/.mysql_history` .
For example can not log `create user`.

How can force cli to store all commands in mysql_history ?
How can fix this problem ?

Answer (score 15):

That behaviour is by design, which as far as I know you can not override.
By default all interactive statements are logged, including the `CREATE USER` statement, **except** when they contain password information.

Although you can add extra conditions that will prevent logging certain additional statements (set either the `--histignore` option or the MYSQL_HISTIGNORE environment variable) or completely stop logging with for instance the [`--batch`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_batch) switch, logging passwords is as far as I know not possible.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-logging.html

> **mysql** ignores for logging purposes statements that match any pattern in the “ignore” list. By default, the pattern list is `"*IDENTIFIED*:*PASSWORD*"`, to ignore statements that refer to passwords.

Comment: Whether possible or not, it's certainly **not desirable**.

Answer (score 1):

Try to:

- set MYSQL_HISTFILE environment variable explicitily
- touch .mysql_history
- chmod 600 .mysql_history

History in not written immediately, but when you exit the client.